# Create activitygroup using mvvmcross and xamarin.droid

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, activitygroup

I want to create a activitygroup using mvvmcross and all its glory. But I can not find an example anywhere. With an Activity we use MvxActivity, but there is not a MvxActivityGroup.

The reason iam doing it, is because i want to have a tabbar with multiple activity groups so the tabbar is visible on all activities.

Any suggestions or links is highly appreciated

EDIT:
Stuart gives a great answer as always and I give the cudos to him, however I ended up doing it differently. 
I used fragments, MvxTabsFragmentActivity and a custom presented. How to do it is shown in http://slodge.blogspot.dk/2013/06/n26-fragments-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html
Furthermore as I understands, activitygroup is decaprecated so it is runnning out of luck anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActivityGroup is itself a custom Activity - it inherits from `Activity`

If you want to add data-binding to any custom Activity, then you can do this using the event source and mvx steps similar to the steps described for `ActionBarActivity` in: http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2013/11/getting-support-v7-working-with.html

If you then want to introduce custom navigation then you can override the default MvvmCross presenter - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup#custom-presenters and http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/presenter-roundup.html